# Nullable types as function parameter in C#

Tags: c#

I saw this in a piece of code and was wondering if someone could help clarifying this for me.

```
public string MethodName(string str, int? x = null)
{
     if(x != null)
     {
          ....
     }
}
```

The second function parameter is where I'm confused:

```
int? x = null
```

I know about Nullable types, but I'm confused about the syntax here, I've never seen this before. Why is there a "= null" in the input parameter? The way that I'm reading it is it's setting x to null and it will never hit that first if, because x is always null.

Comment: It's a default/optional parameter.  If the arg is not specified by the caller, the default value will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here in the method signature `x` is an [optional parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), which means you can omit this argument if you do not want to change the parameter's default value. 
Consider the following calls to this function.

**Call 1** : with two parameters

```
MethodName("AValue",10); // str = AValue and x=10
```

**Call 2** : by skipping optional parameters

```
MethodName("AValue"); // str = AValue and x=null
```

**Note :-**

> To define an optional parameter you should assign a default value to
>   that parameter, so that if it is not specified in the function call
>   the default value will be taken.

Answer (score 4):

int? x = null is a default parameter or optional argument.

 When you pass the value to function it will be

```
MethodName(str,value);

x = value ;
```

Otherwise :

```
MethodName(str);
x = null;
```

So, you have two way to call this function. Using this type to declar the method, the optional argument must place in the last.

Answer (score 2):

it means its giving parameter x an optional value in case a call to the method doesn't supply it with a value.

you can also do this to any type of parameter not nullable only.

Valid calls for MethodName method:

```
string str = "";
int? x = 1;

MethodName(str); //this will work even you only supply the string parameter;

MethodName(str, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's setting the default value for x. Ints are not nullable, so

```
int = null
```

is not valid. Therefore it wouldn't work without the ? type.

Also, this value can be changed. For example:

```
//x will be equal to null
MethodName("string")
//x will be equal to 5
MethodName("string", x: 5)
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

That means that you can call this function two ways:

```
var result = MethodName("X", 5);
```

or

```
var result = MethodName("X");
```

If you don't pass the second parameter it's going to use the default (in this case `null`).